# MS ACCESS export sentence into component words as rows in new table?

Tags: ms-access, split

I have a MS ACCESS query (RAW_DATA) containing short problem descriptions of variable lengths with over a million records in a field (DUMP). The query has already stripped out special characters, double spaces and numbers from this data.

Is there an way to split the field (DUMP) into individual words and post them to a new table (OUTPUT)

```
DUMP
--------------------------------------------
Unable to login
My printer is not connecting to the network
I am unable to login to app ABCD



OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------
Unable
to
login
My
printer
is
not
connecting
to
the
network
I
am
unable
to
login
to
app
ABCD
```

I able to do this with successfully with a macro below in excel, but due to my limited knowledge of I need help with MS access function

```
Sub Step2()

' Split into words

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim l As Long
Dim strSentence As String, rStr As String
Dim varArray As Variant
Dim varItems As Variant

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("DUMP")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("OUTPUT")

ws1.Activate
Range("A1").Select
strSentence = ActiveCell.Value
Do Until strSentence = ""
ws2.Activate
Range("A1").Select
varArray = Split(strSentence, " ")
varItems = varArray
For Each varItems In varArray
ActiveCell.Offset(l).Value = varItems
l = l + 1
Next varItems
ws1.Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
strSentence = ActiveCell.Value

Loop

Set wb = Nothing
Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know about efficient, but suggest loop through recordset, grab field data, split to array, loop array and save each element as record in destination table. Set the destination field as unique to prevent duplicates.

Comment: @June7 I actually just updated my post. I actually want to keep duplicates.

Comment: So data is in an Access table? Learn about opening and looping recordsets in VBA and then saving to table with either an INSERT action SQL or to another recordset object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**June7** & **Erik A** thanks for your help

I used the following post updating your second script and got it to work.

I figured a few commas's were missing

```
Sub GetWordsx()

' MS ACCESS Macro to break space delimited string/sentences in component words as rows into new table
' "01_CLEANED" = Source Table & "DUMP" = Source Field
' "02_WORDS" = Destination Table & "WORDS" = Destination Field
' Credit: June7 @ https://stackoverflow.com/

Dim rsIn As DAO.Recordset, rsOut As DAO.Recordset, db As DAO.Database, aryS As Variant, x As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsIn = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DUMP FROM 01_CLEANED")
Set rsOut = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT WORDS FROM 02_WORDS WHERE 1=0")
Do While Not rsIn.EOF
    aryS = Split(rsIn!DUMP, " ")
    For x = 0 To UBound(aryS)
        rsOut.AddNew
        rsOut!WORDS = aryS(x)
        rsOut.Update
    Next
    rsIn.MoveNext
Loop
MsgBox "That's All Folks!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Would be nice to accept an answer if it resolved your issue instead of just mimicking. What do you mean by "commas's were missing"?

Answer (score 0):

VBA in Access could be like:

```
Sub GetWords()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, db As DAO.Database, aryS As Variant, x As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Dump FROM Raw_Data")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    aryS = Split(rs!Dump, " ")
    For x = 0 To UBound(aryS)
        db.Execute "INSERT INTO Output(Word) VALUES('" & aryS(x) & "')"
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub GetWords()
Dim rsIn As DAO.Recordset, rsOut As DAO.Recordset db As DAO.Database, aryS As Variant, x As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsIn = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Dump FROM Raw_Data")
Set rsOut = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Word FROM Output WHERE 1=0")
Do While Not rsIn.EOF
    aryS = Split(rsIn!Dump, " ")
    For x = 0 To UBound(aryS)
        rsOut.AddNew
        rsOut!Word = aryS(x)
        rsOut.Update
    Next
    rsIn.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help

But both codes don't run unfortunately.

First one produced a "Invalid use of Property" error for line 
```
db = CurrentDb
```
and the Second one wont compile or run as it shows an error on row

```
Dim rsIn As DAO.Recordset, rsOut As DAO.Recordset db As DAO.Database, aryS As Variant, x As Integer
```

Comment: That should obviously be `Set db = CurrentDb`, simple typo for that error, Also, go with the second one, it has a lot less overhead and is not sensitive to SQL injection, the first option is plain bad.